# java : converting anonymous inner class to concrete class

Tags: java, swing

I have the following anonymous class

```
box = new JComboBox(filename);
...
    box.addItemListener(
                    new ItemListener() {
                        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event )
                        {
                            if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                                picture.setIcon(pics[box.getSelectedIndex()]);



                        }
                    }
               );
```

I'm trying to convert this to a concrete class with the following:

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.Event.*;
import javax.swing.*; 
    public class Gui extends JFrame { 
    ...

    public Gui () {
    box.addItemListener(new Handler());
    ...        
    add(box);    
    }

        class Handler extends ItemListener {

            public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent e)  {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    picture.setIcon(pics[box.getSelectedIndex()]);

                }//end if 

            }//end itemstatechanged 
        }
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?
the error i get says it can't find the symbol ItemListener

Comment: Whenever you have an error or exception. Post as much of it as possible. If it points to a specific line include that as well.

Comment: Beaten four times at once. Still, I'd like to mention that all modern IDEs I know of support "convert anonymous to inner" refactoring which does this for you automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ItemListener` is an `interface`, you need to use the keyword `implements`.

```
class Handler implements ItemListener {
```

Also, when I create my listeners I usually make them a private member variable in case I want to reuse them.

```
private ItemListener setIconHandler = new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent e)  {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            picture.setIcon(pics[box.getSelectedIndex()]);

        }//end if 

    }//end itemstatechanged 
};
```

This way you can reuse the listener, and you don't have to define a class that you are only going to use once or twice.

Also, for completeness, you need to fix your imports.  This [was not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818636/java-converting-anonymous-inner-class-to-concrete-class/4818660#4818660) [caught by me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818636/java-converting-anonymous-inner-class-to-concrete-class/4818672#4818672), but by other people answering the question.  You should use `import java.awt.event.ItemListener;` instead of `import java.awt.Event.*;`.

Comment: The private member variable is very slick.  After declaring the private member variable outside the constructor, how would you reuse it?  would it be box.addItemListener(setIconHandler); ?

Answer (score 2):

You also need to add import statements for the ItemListener and ItemEvent.

Comment: @Justin, looks like he is importing  Event.* as opposed to event.*

Comment: @Justin 'jjnguy' Nelson: Not quite. He's importing Event.* note event.*

Comment: @sblundy, Yeah, I see that now.  Good catch.

Comment: Just to be clear, there is a class in java.awt called Event. The children of that are what's being imported.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `implements ItemListener`?

And you'll need to import it via:

`import java.awt.event.ItemListener;`

`import java.awt.Event.*;` imports the inner classes of the class Event in java.awt.

Answer (score 0):

`ItemListener` is an interface, so you need to `implement` it, not `extend` from it